# Can I connect a Nokia Lumia 800 to an Ethernet cable using a micro-USB to LAN adapter?

Tags: 7.8, nokia-lumia-800, usb

I am using a Nokia Lumia 800, with Windows Phone 7.8. I have a LAN cable through which I can access the internet.

Can I connect my Lumia to the LAN via a Micro-USB to LAN adapter?

*I know I can connect with Zune, but I want to use the internet without turning on my PC.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No**, it is not possible to use the phone's **Micro-USB** with an Ethernet cable for internet access. Even with a USB Ethernet adapter, the phone doesn't have the driver support.

Try a WiFi router or a SIM card with a data connection to avail of internet access without turning on your PC.